# Jackson, move dynamic property value one level up

Tags: java, jackson

I have problem with modelling server responses, some of them look like that:

```
{
    "_links":{
        "self":{
            "href":"http:\/\/example.com"
        }
    },
    "_embedded":{
        "category":{
           <...data...>
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "_links":{
        "self":{
            "href":"http:\/\/example.com"
        }
    },
    "_embedded":{
        "episodes":[
           <...list_data...>
        ]
    }
}
```

It seems that "_embedded" property has only one JSON object and that object has only one property ( named differently ) with actual data.

I would like to create some kind of generic POJO class to support those kind of responses, something like:

```
public abstract class EmbeddedResponse<T> {

    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    private T embedded;

    public T getEmbedded() {
        return embedded;
    }

    ... <other_members> ...
}

public class CategoriesResponse extends EmbeddedResponse<List<Category>> {

}
```

Where calling 'getEmbedded()' would return list of categories ( or episodes, or anything ).

I am working with custom deserialization now, but without much success, I would like to keep code base minimal.

Comment: I believe `@JsonTypeInfo` can do what you want... But I have never used it in this scenario :/

Comment: @JsonTypeInfo refers to slightly different problem, if I would operate on collection of polymorphic types

Comment: No, I didn't mean that; use it on classes which are _elements_ of the list, not the list itself

Comment: @fge I am not sure if I get you right. The only reason I want to create that EmbeddedResponse class is that I would like to have universal container class for some of server responses. JsonTypeInfo is responsible for holding information about JSONObject type used in code. In this case I see no need for using it, but could you provide full answer with example below ?

Comment: Well, it seems to me that in all your JSON responses, the value of the property is a list, this is why I suggested that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, abstract POJO class:

```
public class EmbeddedResponse<T>  {

    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    @JsonDeserialize( using = EmbeddedResponseDeserializer.class )
    private T embedded;

    public T getEmbedded() {

        return embedded;
    }
}
```

POJO for actual response:

```
public class CategoriesResponse extends EmbeddedResponse<List<Category>> {

}
```

Deserializer for JSON in question:

```
public class EmbeddedResponseDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> implements ContextualDeserializer {

private JavaType javaType;

@Override
public Object deserialize( JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt ) throws IOException {

    ObjectCodec objectCodec = jsonParser.getCodec();

    JsonNode node = objectCodec.readTree(jsonParser);

    // Get first it might require correction
    String fieldName = node.fieldNames().next();

    JsonNode skippedNode = node.get( fieldName );

    return objectCodec.readValue( skippedNode.traverse(), javaType );
}

@Override
public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual( DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property ) throws JsonMappingException {

    javaType = property.getType();

    return this;
}
```

}

It might require more tweeks but at this point this solution is working

Answer (score -1):

I would use the Java 8 [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) object when modelling the objects. This way you get a flexible model and nice programming model by e.g. using the [ifPresent-method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-).

So, the root class could be modelled along the lines of:

```
public class Response {
    private Embedded embedded;
    private Links links;

    @JsonCreator
    public Response(
            @JsonProperty("_links") final Links links, 
            @JsonProperty("_embedded") final Embedded embedded) {
        this.links = links;
        this.embedded = embedded;
    }

    public Embedded embedded() {
        return embedded;
    }

    public Links links() {
        return links;
    }
}
```

The object that defines the embedded content (i.e. category or episodes) could be modelled like this:

```
public class Embedded {
    private final Category category;
    private final List<Episode> episodes;

    @JsonCreator
    public Embedded(
            @JsonProperty("episodes") final List<Episode> episodes, 
            @JsonProperty("category") final Category category) {
        this.episodes = episodes;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Optional<Category> category() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(category);
    }

    public Optional<List<Episode>> episodes() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(episodes);
    }
}
```

When programming towards these objects the following pattern could be used:

```
final InputStream resource = ...; // retrieve a stream somehow

// Map the stream to the response object
final Response response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(resource, Response.class);

// Use the Optional-style for processing category data
response.embedded().category().ifPresent(category -> {
    // do category stuff with the Category-object
});

// Once more, use the Optional-style - this time for processing episodes data    
response.embedded().episodes().ifPresent(episodes -> {
    // do episodes stuff with the List of Episodes
});
```

Comment: Embedded class in not universal in this case, I have responses with different key names, not only "episodes", "category" and I needed to solve that problem on Android, so I cannot use Java 8.

Comment: How many different key names are we talking about? Tens, hundreds or simply *x*? Is your plan to create subclasses for each of them?

Comment: TBH I have no idea, so far I counted 5 of them. I don't like solution with one container that could hold many different kind of data - it is very confusing. Imagine the same class with 30 different types of data, constructor will be massive, so many accessor methods.

Comment: I agree, too many accessor-methods makes the code hard to read/maintain. But, loads of "simple" subclasses is also a bit of a code smell. I simply assumed two cases since that was in your example.

If there are too too many types you can probably save the *embedded*-data in a `JsonNode`-object and create some pattern for creating your data structures (I mean from JsonNode to Category or so).

Comment: Interesting approach, I agree that tons of simple classes is kinda wierd, since each class has like 5 lines of code ( actually 2 would be sufficient ). On the other hand it guarantee type safety, no need for type checks, and creating Category (or something else) from JsonNode is what Jackson ObjectMapper is already doing, besides this kind of lazy loading may slow down Android application. In the end I think it is less code to support in future, which IMO is always better.